# Leaked intent receiver rxAndroidble UPDATED

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I noticed that in the compose method this observable could be binded to an activity lifecycle to do the desired unsubscription, the problem is that i am doing this in a service, so i cant use this library, or at least i dont know how to get this service lifecycle and bind the observable to it:

```
return bleDevice
            .establishConnection(false)
            .takeUntil(disconnectTriggerSubject)
            //.compose(RxLifecycle.bindUntilEvent(MISSINGACTIVITYLIFECYCLE, ActivityEvent.DESTROY))
            .doOnUnsubscribe(this::onDestroy)
            .compose(new ConnectionSharingAdapter());
```

i am using RxandroidBle to scan numerous devices used as interface of for a sensoring system, all goes fine, i do this in a background service, the problem is when i stop the service i cant unsuscribe to that broadcast, i used the example provided in the repo. (UPDATED)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to tackle this problem:

1. Unsubscribe by hand (my favourite)

Assign the `Subscription` resulting from `.subscribe()` to a property and then in service `onStop()` just call:

```
public void onStop() {
  if (subscription != null) {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    subscription = null;
  }
}
```

If you have more than one `Subscription` to unsubscribe from you could check out what is a [`SerialSubscription`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/SerialSubscription.html) or [`CompositeSubscription`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/CompositeSubscription.html) which may be useful.

2. Use `disconnectTriggerSubject`

Making the `disconnectTriggerSubject` to accept any value would make the `RxBleDevice.establishConnection()` to be unsubscribed so the connection will get closed. The downstream may not be aware that it should also unsubscribe. One could pass a special `Throwable` to the subject which would be passed down to all subscribers.

Just make sure that the subscribers would treat the `Throwable` passed differently than other

3. Implement [`RxLifecycle` callbacks](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle/blob/1.x/rxlifecycle/src/main/java/com/trello/rxlifecycle/LifecycleProvider.java) for your Service

Probably most tedious path to take. Especially when you found out that [`RxLifecycle` is not a perfect solution](http://blog.danlew.net/2017/08/02/why-not-rxlifecycle/)

Comment: Thx Dariusz, im going to try the different approaches and let you know what happens :)